# Overflow issue on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

As you can see from the screen I have a problem with my portion of the page, I state that all the other sections of the site that have overflow work very well. I have tried several times to review the code but I do not know what it can be ... also put the code of the portion that does not work below

```
<div class="messageDiv w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-start overflow-scroll relative text-xl lg:text-xs">
            <!--prototipo di messaggio-->

            <% for(var i=messages.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){ %>
              <% if(messages[i].id_user == userId){ %>

              <div class="flex justify-end items-center">
                <div class="talk-bubble tri-right radius right-in bg-gray-900 text-white w-auto px-5 py-2 mb-2 lg:mb-1 mr-5">
                  <div class="talktext flex flex-col justify-center items-center">

                    <p class="text-left w-full"><%=messages[i].text%></p>
                    <div class="info-message flex justify-start items-center w-full pt-1 mt-1 overflow-hidden">
                      <p class="title text-rigth username"><%=messages[i].username%></p>
                      <i class="fas fa-circle text-white px-2"></i>
                      <i class="far fa-clock title"></i>
                      <p class="title ml-1"><%=messages[i].date.getHours()%>:<%=messages[i].date.getMinutes()%></p>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <% } else{ %>
                <div class="flex justify-start items-center">
                  <div class="talk-bubble tri-left radius left-in bg-black text-white w-auto px-5 py-2 ml-5 mb-2 lg:mb-1">
                    <div class="talktext flex flex-col justify-center items-center">

                      <p class="text-left w-full"><%=messages[i].text%></p>
                      <div class="info-message flex justify-end items-center w-full pt-1 mt-1 overflow-hidden flex-no-wrap">
                        <p class="text-giallo text-rigth username"><%=messages[i].username%></p>
                        <i class="fas fa-circle text-white px-2"></i>
                        <i class="far fa-clock text-giallo"></i>
                        <p class="text-giallo ml-1"><%=messages[i].date.getHours()%>:<%=messages[i].date.getMinutes()%></p>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              <% } %>
            <% } %>

            <!--end-->
          </div>
```

I use tailwind as a css framework and it's how you can guess a project in node.js.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
For mobile devices use:-
touch-action: auto | none | [ [ pan-x | pan-left | pan-right ] || [ pan-y | pan-up|pan-down ] || pinch-zoom ] | manipulation
```

This is same as overflow axis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply in the meantime, but where should I put it?

Comment: put it in a  container that you want scrollable like this:- touch-action: pan-y;

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. But the problem here isn't that the touch doesn't work, the elements don't overflow which is different. it is as if everyone should enter the div and therefore obviously overlap.